# Avoid saving returned data to ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have an ngResource object like this:

```
[...].factory('Event', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/events/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        resume: {url: '/events/:id/resume'},
        signUpload: {url: '/events/:id/sign-upload'},
    });
}]);
```

But when I call `myModel.$resume();` or `myModel.$signUpload()` the returned data gets automatically saved to my model. However, the returned data is not my model attributes, but actually another completely different return.

I need to avoid auto-saving the returned data from the server. Is there anything out-of-the-box to do that? I couldn't find it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can try to not use resource, but create service.

```
app.service('eventService', ['$http, $q', function ($http, $q) {
    this.signUpload = function(eventId) {
       var defer = $q.defer();

       $http.get('/events/' + eventId + '/sign-upload')
         .then(function(result) {
             defer.resolve(result.data);
         })
         .catch(function(err) {
             defer.reject(new Error(err));
         });

       return defer.promise;

    }


    // same for other function
}]);
```

Inject this service in controller, and just do **eventService.signUpload(eventId);**

Comment: But I want to use the `ngService`. It provides most of functionality I need. I still use the `$get`, `$save` [...] methods. How to prevent the default behaviour is the question...

Comment: You can have both, ngResource and ngService, resource type is mostly for CRUD operations, and you can have eventService for other purposes... In our projects we use only services, because they are more friendly to unit tests.

Comment: Then I can continue using `Event.$signUpload({id: myModel.id}, cb)`. It is the same thing... But still, I would have to to that for every model I have, that needs to call an api that do not returns the self object...

Comment: if you need to pass multiple "event"-s, in services you can pass not one Id, but multiple ones, and pass them as query params to your backend...

Comment: I want the action to be built into the ngResource, this is only one model of many. ngResource does a really great job at that, but fails only at this point until now